# MySQL, how to query among intervals?

Tags: mysql

Its like I want to do a `for i` cycle. Table:

```
amount value
1      1
4      10
9      11
14     12
```

and I want to get 10 for asking amount `5`. So, the "test" results would be:

```
1 => 1
2 => 1
3 => 1
4 => 10
5 => 10
6 => 10
7 => 10
8 => 10
9 => 11
10 => 11
11 => 11
12 => 11
13 => 11
14 => 12
```

but WHERE amount = 5 wont work. How to set this where with intervals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
select t.value
from table t
where t.amount <= 5
order by t.amount desc
limit 1;
```

Comment: yea, exactly. Was it hard? I couldnt figured it

Comment: It takes some practice to move from procedural thinking (i.e. loops) to set-based thinking.  Both are very useful, so the practice is worth the effort.